# Undo several commits in git which have not pushed to remote

Tags: git, github

I have run git status and

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want undo all the 4 commits and changes not staged for commit before commiting to my remote repository. How can i do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will throw away all local changes in the working tree and the four latest commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

Answer (score 40):

You can also run the following to reset to the remote's HEAD:

```
git reset --hard <REMOTE>/<BRANCH_NAME>
```

Ex:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```